# I am confused on the issue,how to use array_udiff

Tags: php

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$b = array(1,6,3,4,5);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_udiff($a,$b,function($a,$b){
    return ($a === $b)? 0:1;
}));
```

As the manual said:
It should returns an array containing all the values of array1 that are not present in any of the other arguments.
If only two arrays to be compared, I think it would be like `array_diff()`.
I would expect this to return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
)
```

However it returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [4] => 5
)
```

Comment: I am not sure, but perhaps it does use the return value of your comparison function beyond "equals" or "doesn't equal" and it actually considers whether something is "higher" or "lower". Have you tried correctly returning `< 0`, `0` or `> 0`?

Comment: @deceze thanks,as I do it like this,because I get it from a book.so contents of the books can not be completely believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the value_compare_func parameter of `array_udiff()` , "The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second."

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php

This fixes the problem, and returns an array with an item of `2`.

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$b = array(1,6,3,4,5);
echo "<pre>";

print_r(array_udiff($a,$b,function($a,$b){
    if ($a < $b) {
            return -1;
        } elseif ($a > $b) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        };
}));
```