# About array_udiff,I want to ask again

Tags: php

2 days ago,I have asked this question ( [I am confused on the issue,how to use array_udiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061297/i-am-confused-on-the-issue-how-to-use-array-udiff) ).
I'm sorry to discuss this question once again.
Although I have got the solution to the problem, but I'm still confused on this question:
demo1:

```
function myfunction($v1,$v2) 
{
if ($v1===$v2)
    {
    return 0;
    }
return 1;
}
$a1=array("a"=>"Cat","b"=>"Dog","c"=>"Horse");
$a2=array(1=>"Cat",2=>"Dog",3=>"Fish");
print_r(array_udiff($a1,$a2,"myfunction"));
```

output:

```
Array ( [c] => Horse )
```

demo2:

```
function myfunction($v1,$v2) 
{
if ($v1===$v2)
    {
    return 0;
    }
return 1;
}
$a1 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$a2 = array(1,6,3,4,5);
print_r(array_udiff($a1,$a2,"myfunction"));
```

I expect this to return:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 )
```

but the output is:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [4] => 5 )
```

Yes,I know, I need to according to the php manual,
demo3:

```
function myfunction($v1,$v2) {
    if ($v1 < $v2) {
        return -1;
    } elseif ($v1 > $v2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
$a1 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$a2 = array(1,6,3,4,5);
print_r(array_udiff($a1,$a2,"myfunction"));
```

output:

```
Array ( [1] => 2 )// it's right
```

What I am confused is that why the demo1 is ok.

Comment: What output did you expect with the callback function you use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result you're getting is because you're using callback which returns `1` and `0`. While logically it's justified (i.e. `1` means "equal" and `0` means "not equal") - PHP expects callback that return **full comparison** - thus, not only on *equality* - but also *greater and less* comparison.

To understand why it is so you need to understand how PHP processes calculation of arrays difference. It's not just simple walking through both arrays. PHP will *sort* arrays first, then will do checks. That is because simple walk (nested loop) will result in `O(n*m)` complexity, while sorting arrays first will result in approximately `O(k log(k)), k=max(n, m)` complexity for two arrays of size `n` and `m`. And to sort elements via user-defined callback it's *not enough* to check elements equality. You'll need to know their order, that's why *less/greater* comparison is needed.

So, as a conclusion: you can only use callback with full `-1/0/1` values in it's result. If your callback returns something different, results **will be unpredictable** - that's why they may be *"correct"* and *"wrong"* on different input data.

Comment: So complicated it is!